# SQL - Listing Items that have multiple items

Tags: sql

Ok so the scenario is...

There is a client with the ID in the Database as 684.

For this particular client there are Invoices.

Some of these invoices have multiple Jobs attached to them.

I need to list all of the Jobs that are on Invoices more than once and which these jobs are.

I'm new to SQL and would like to learn how it would be done.

My code so far

```
SELECT
    i.InvoiceNo
FROM
    Job j
    INNER JOIN Client c ON j.ClientID = c.ClientID
    INNER JOIN Invoice i ON c.ClientID = i.ClientID
    INNER JOIN InvoiceItem ii ON i.InvoiceID = ii.InvoiceID
WHERE
    c.ClientID = 684
    AND
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT JobNo) FROM InvoiceItem) > 1
```

Anything you need to know ask and i will try to help.

I basically dont know how to display my result from the subselect in my main select i guess.

Comment: How are invoices and jobs related? I can't see from your query; no table definitions either.

Comment: The InvoiceItem has a column named JobNo, sorry quite new to this.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: SQL Manager Studio 2016

Answer (score 0):

Fistly, use HAVING to filter data

```
SELECT
    COUNT(ii.JobNo), ii.JobNo
FROM
    Job AS j
    INNER JOIN Client AS c ON j.ClientID = c.ClientID
    INNER JOIN Invoice AS i ON c.ClientID = i.ClientID
    INNER JOIN InvoiceItem AS ii ON i.InvoiceID = ii.InvoiceID
WHERE
    c.ClientID = 684
GROUP BY JobNo
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ii.JobNo) > 1
```